# Typescript/Javscript Language server protocol text highlighting

Tags: javascript, typescript, language-server-protocol

I want to implement text highlighting on my Language server protocol that works on plaintext.
Like I want to highlight words like "hi" per example. i didn't know where to do it server or client .
Also im using my package.json :
"activationEvents": [
"onLanguage:plaintext"
],
So its working on plain text{txt file).